# How do I vote on Slashdot?

Tags: slashdot

It's a very silly question, but how do I vote? I've noticed that posts have score, and I assume it's calculated by user votes, but I haven't found the UI element to cast my vote. I am of course logged in.

Also, how do I mark a post/comment as "insightful", "humoristic" etc. ?

[image]

Comment: Those tags are given by Moderators

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Slashdot has adopted the interesting system of giving logged in users randomly a number of 'moderation points', which can be used to moderate posts as you describe. You can increase the chances of getting these points by being logged in and browsing comments and by having been a member for a certain length of time, but it is largely a matter of chance.

There is a (very) old write up [here](http://slashdot.org/moderation.shtml) that is quite in-depth on the how and why. Some of the details may be a little different now but the mechanics are largely the same. The [FAQ](http://slashdot.org/faq) topic covers it in less detail.

Answer (score -2):

After selecting all the drop downs the way you want, you can click on a new "moderate button" all the way on the bottom of the thread.

Comment: there's edit history _right_ infront of you. Click on the edited <timestamp>. Also, I don't see the need to rant about why it sucks/doesn't.